# Why can I not call Core Data Accessors on super?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, overloading, super

### Background

I'm using the rather excellent [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to auto generate my core data accessors.

mogenerator structures the classes as following:

```
NSManagedObject
    _JGTrainingBase
        JGTrainingBase
            _JGTrainingGroup 
                JGTrainingGroup
```

- Classes starting with an underscore are machine generated with core data accessors by mogenerator.
- Classes without an underscore are human editable ones so you can put custom methods in there and not have it overwritten when you change your data model and rerun mogenerator.
- The training group entity has to-many relationship called "children".
- I'm using the Core Data accessors to modify my relationships.

### What I Want

I want to update duration - a transient attribute - before adding a children object.

### The Problem

**My Code**

```
@implementation JGTrainingGroup
...
-(void)addChildrenObject:(JGTrainingGroup *)value_ {
    [self updateDuration];
    [super addChildrenObject:value_];
}
...
@end
```

But when I call this method, I get an error message:

```
[JGTrainingGroup addChildrenObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10667fa30
```

**Generated Code**

```
@interface _JGTrainingBase : NSManagedObject {}
// Method declarations
@end

@interface _JGTrainingBase (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addChildrenObject:(JGTrainingBase*)value_;
- (void)removeChildrenObject:(JGTrainingBase*)value_;
// Lots more methods
@end
```

**Questions**

1. Why does super not respond to the addChildrenObject: method? Is it something to do with these being added in a category style?
2. How can I access the Core Data generated method from a subclass?

**Note**

I realise I can add the children object to the set using primitiveValueForKey: and similar, but that means I'm rewriting the core data accessors, thus wasting my time and probably making my code buggy. I trust Apple's methods would be better than anything I could write.

Thanks for any input on helping me understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have two subclasses of NSManagedObject where the parent class implements a dynamic property and its subclass (the grandchild of NSManagedObject) overrides the methods for the property, those overrides cannot call super.

says [ADC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html)

You can not call super as those accessors are generated on demand by the runtime

Comment: Ah. That makes total sense. I really should have read the docs more thoroughly. It even has examples of accessors I can implement myself. Are there any other ways you can think of to do this without writing a whole bunch more code though? If not, I guess I'll just copy the example code and modify a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of a general solution to this problem. If you want to add the same functionality of updating a timestamp on accessing setters to many classes, aspect oriented programming might be worth a try. The Obj-C runtime can do lot's of crazy stuff.